# Flutter also throws to the login screen when the keyboard opens(Solved)

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, keyboard, textfield

I am developing an application in flutter, now I only have screens such as login, login and forgot password. When I click on the textfield in the application, the keyboard appears and throws me to the login page as if I have just opened the application, and the same problem occurs when the keyboard opens on the login screen.

edit: this is problem :

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage()));//Good boy it's work

      // Navigator.of(context)
      //     .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage()));//Bad boy it's a problem choice
```

```
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<LoginPage> createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double buttonHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.08;
    final double buttonWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6;
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.27,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                      begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                      end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                      colors: [Colors.orange, Colors.pink]),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(60),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(60),
                  )),
              child: Image.asset(
                'assets/images/logo.png',
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            const Text(
              'Giriş Yap',
              style: titleText,
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                const Text(
                  "Henüz bir hesabınız yok mu? ",
                  style: subTitleText,
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => const RegisterPage(),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    'Kayıt ol',
                    style: subTitleText.copyWith(
                      color: Colors.pink,
                      decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
              child: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width: 1),
                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                      bottomRight: Radius.circular(30),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(30),
                    )),
                child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.75,
                        child: TextField(
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            setState(() {});
                          },
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'Telefon Numarası',
                              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.phone_android)),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.75,
                        child: TextField(
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            setState(() {});
                          },
                          obscureText: true,
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'Şifre',
                              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.password)),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                        child: InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => const ResetPasswordPage(),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0),
                            child: Text(
                              'Şifreni mi unuttun?',
                              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                              style: subTitleText.copyWith(
                                color: Colors.pink,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          ),
                          minimumSize: Size(buttonWidth, buttonHeight),
                        ),
                        child: const Text(
                          'Giriş Yap',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ]),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class RegisterPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const RegisterPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<RegisterPage> createState() => _RegisterPageState();
}

class _RegisterPageState extends State<RegisterPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double buttonHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.08;
    final double buttonWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6;
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.27,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                    end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                    colors: [Colors.orange, Colors.pink]),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(60),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(60),
                ),
              ),
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Positioned(
                    top: 25,
                    left: 20,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => const LoginPage()));
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                        child: const Icon(Icons.home,
                            color: Colors.white, size: 50),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Center(
                    child: Image.asset(
                      'assets/images/logo.png',
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            const Text(
              'Kayıt Ol',
              style: titleText,
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            const Text(
              "Bilgilerini gir kayıt ol ve hesabına giriş yap",
              style: subTitleText,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
              child: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.55,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width: 1),
                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                      bottomRight: Radius.circular(30),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(30),
                    )),
                child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.75,
                        child: const TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'İsim Soyisim',
                              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person)),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.75,
                        child: const TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'Telefon Numarası',
                              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.phone_android)),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.75,
                        child: const TextField(
                          obscureText: true,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'Şifre',
                              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.password)),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.75,
                        child: const TextField(
                          obscureText: true,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'Şifreni Tekrar Gir',
                              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.password)),
                        ),
                      ),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          ),
                          minimumSize: Size(buttonWidth, buttonHeight),
                        ),
                        child: const Text(
                          'Kayıt Ol',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ]),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

problem gif
I only select the textfields, I do not click on any other field
https://gifyu.com/image/SduIl

resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false, I tried the property singlechildscrool, I changed the textfields, I changed the sizedbox to container but they didn't work

************************Solve************************

Hi, I'm writing to you with good news, I found the problem, the part that broke the application was the splashscreen side, but I don't understand what the problem is here.

```
class SplashPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SplashPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {
      Navigator.of(context)
          .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage()));
    });
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: SizedBox(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: Image.asset(
          'assets/images/splash_screen.png',
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try extracting
MediaQuery.of(context).size.height to a variable called heightOfScreen
same with width and relocate the initialization to initState
and instead of using MediaQuery inside build method, use the variable `'heightOfScreen' and 'widthOfScreen'`

```
late final heightOfScreen, widthOfScreen;

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
heightOfScreen =MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
widthOfScreen=MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
}
```

And Use like heightOfScreen*0.5;